# Android studio AssertionError: Don't invoke waitForSmartMode from inside read action in dumb mode

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I have been facing this problem since i updated to Android Studio 2.1 RC . A quick google search shows that the problem is being faced by developers using Android Studio 2.1. The issue appeared in April and a solution have not been found yet.
[image: Logs]
[image: Reported afew days ago]

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. I fixed it with:
 
1. Build, Clean project.
 
2. Build, Build APK.
3. Build, Generate Signed APK

Answer (score 1):

I ended up needing to delete the projects cache directory. You can just delete the `.gradle` directory so that it can be regenerated.